# Cant run command `mvn spring-boot:run`

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-3.9.5

I am encountering an error with Maven in both IntelliJ IDEA and the terminal. The error occurs when I try to execute the `mvn spring-boot:run` command.

Errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

- The `mvn spring-boot:run` command cannot be run in the terminal directly.
- However, if I first run `test` and `deploy` from the IntelliJ GUI, the `mvn spring-boot:run` command runs well.
- Running `test` and `deploy` through the terminal does not work, and subsequently, `mvn spring-boot:run` fails as well.
- I've tried creating a new project through IntelliJ to replicate the issue, and the same behavior is observed.
- I already surfed through several forum threads.

**Environment:** Linux

- Java Version: 21
- Maven Version: 3.9.4
- IntelliJ IDEA Version: v2023. 3

Why is `mvn spring-boot:run` only working after running `test` and `deploy` from IntelliJ's GUI and not directly from the terminal? Ive looked through my pom and correct $JAVA_HOME version.

[image]

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What are the error and failure messages? They can't be explained if you don't provide them.

Comment: My bad, I just added them. But like I mentioned, the command works only after running `test` or `deploy`.

Comment: IDEA's Terminal may use a system environment different to the one IDEA itself and or even OS Command Prompt uses. Try running mvn --version from IDEA Terminal and from IDEA directly (via a Run Configuration) this will probably help to highlight the discrepancy.

Comment: @romanv-jb Run and the terminal use java 21. The only difference is RUN runs Maven 3.6.3. Could that be the problem? But its actually odd bc this old version runs correctly but the terminal newer version (3.9.4) fails.